# how to use LINQ to query a generic collection

Tags: c#, generics

I wanted to know the way to LINQ a generic collection.

My Customer class is as

```
 class Customer
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
    }
```

My collection class is

```
class genericCollection<T> : CollectionBase
{
    public void add(T GenericObject)
    {
        this.List.Add(GenericObject);
    }
}
```

Then I add some data to customer collection

```
  genericCollection<Customer> customers = new genericCollection<Customer>();
  customers.add(new Customer {id= "1",Name="Andy"});

  customers.add(new Customer { id = "2", Name = "MArk" });
  customers.add(new Customer { id = "3", Name = "Jason" });
  customers.add(new Customer { id = "4", Name = "Alex" });
```

Now i can iterate through customers object using a foreach loop but how can i linq it.

I want to use something like

```
var query =  from c in customers
             select c;
```

But I am not able to successfully cast it.

Regards,
Sab

Comment: Why are you using a custom collection?

Comment: what do you suggest?Anyway i was trying this as a test pilot for LINQ.

Comment: I would suggest using the List<T> class instead of a custom collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some answers suggest using `customers.OfType<Customer>`; this tests the type of every object in the collection before converting it.  You know that each object is of that type, so you don't need the runtime type check.  For that reason, you should use `customers.Cast<Customer>` instead.

Having said that, I agree that it would be better not to use `CollectionBase` in the first place; it would be better to use a generic collection type; if you prefer to define your own collection type, then you should derive from (or delegate to) a generic collection.

Answer (score 5):

try to change your query to the following (assuming that your `CollectionBase` implements `IEnumerable`):

```
var query = from c in customers.OfType<Customer>() select c;
```

or let your `genericCollection<T>` implement `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: Thanks @Tobias.I tried the oftype but forgot to put round braces.

Comment: @user1131926 since all objects in `customers` are known to be of type `Customer`, it would be more efficient to use `from c in customers.Cast<Customer>() select c`

Answer (score 2):

The LINQ standard query operators are extension methods defined for `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>`. You could try:

```
class genericCollection<T> : Collection<T>
```

or use another collection type such as `List<T>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the `IEnumerable<T>` interface:

```
public class genericCollection<T>: CollectionBase, IEnumerable<T>{}
```

Comment: But doing this worked without using IEnumerable                    var query = from c in customers.OfType<Customer>()
                        where c.Name == "Mark"
                        select c;

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you derive from `CollectionBase`. You should also implement `ICollection<T>` and no cast is needed anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify type in LINQ query:

```
var query = from Customer c in customers select c;
```

or implement `IEnumerable<T>` for eg:

```
class genericCollection<T> : CollectionBase, IEnumerable<T>
{
    public void add(T GenericObject)
    {
        this.List.Add(GenericObject);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.List.Cast<T>().GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lolo.Just implemented the IEnumerator.Thanks all for the help

Answer (score 0):

Use **Select**:

```
customers.Select(x => {...})
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with:

```
    public void add(T GenericObject)
    {
        this.List.Add(GenericObject);
    }
    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.List.OfType<T>().GetEnumerator();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, there is a library which provides strongly-typed, queryable collections in typescript.

These collections are:

- List
- Dictionary

The library is called **ts-generic-collections-linq**.

Source code on GitHub:

https://github.com/VeritasSoftware/ts-generic-collections

NPM:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-generic-collections-linq

With this library, you can create collections (like `List<T>`) and query them as shown below.

```
    let owners = new List<Owner>();

    let owner = new Owner();
    owner.id = 1;
    owner.name = "John Doe";
    owners.add(owner);

    owner = new Owner();
    owner.id = 2;
    owner.name = "Jane Doe";
    owners.add(owner);    

    let pets = new List<Pet>();

    let pet = new Pet();
    pet.ownerId = 2;
    pet.name = "Sam";
    pet.sex = Sex.M;

    pets.add(pet);

    pet = new Pet();
    pet.ownerId = 1;
    pet.name = "Jenny";
    pet.sex = Sex.F;

    pets.add(pet);

    //query to get owners by the sex/gender of their pets
    let ownersByPetSex = owners.join(pets, owner => owner.id, pet => pet.ownerId, (x, y) => new OwnerPet(x,y))
                               .groupBy(x => [x.pet.sex])
                               .select(x =>  new OwnersByPetSex(x.groups[0], x.list.select(x => x.owner)));

    expect(ownersByPetSex.toArray().length === 2).toBeTruthy();

    expect(ownersByPetSex.toArray()[0].sex == Sex.F).toBeTruthy();
    expect(ownersByPetSex.toArray()[0].owners.length === 1).toBeTruthy();
    expect(ownersByPetSex.toArray()[0].owners.toArray()[0].name == "John Doe").toBeTruthy();

    expect(ownersByPetSex.toArray()[1].sex == Sex.M).toBeTruthy();
    expect(ownersByPetSex.toArray()[1].owners.length == 1).toBeTruthy();
    expect(ownersByPetSex.toArray()[1].owners.toArray()[0].name == "Jane Doe").toBeTruthy();
```